# How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert JSON object string to a JavaScript array.

This my JSON object:

```
{"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7}
```

And I want to have:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

data.addRows([
    ['2013-01-21', 1],
    ['2013-01-22', 7]
]);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Cheating -> `string.split(',')`

Comment: @adeneo he wants array in array, with your method it will be just one array

Comment: If your data is a AJAX response consider to use data.responseText in order to get the core data.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
var json_data = {"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7};
var result = [];

for(var i in json_data)
    result.push([i, json_data [i]]);


var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MV5rj/

Comment: I would like something like this:
2013-01-21 ==> 1
2013-01-22 ==> 7
(like a hashtable)

Comment: @user1960311 That's what you have now

Answer (score 103):

If you have a well-formed JSON string, you should be able to do

```
var as = JSON.parse(jstring);
```

I do this all the time when transfering arrays through AJAX.

Comment: +1 for JSON.parse().  At this point it has broad browser support: http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: This seems to return an Object but not array. Right ?

Comment: It will return whatever object or collection of objects you serialized.

Comment: IMO this better ansver then actepted one.

Comment: Good one than accepted and fast as well @aggaton

Answer (score 69):

Suppose you have:

```
var j = {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4"};
```

You could get the values with (supported in practically all browser versions):

```
Object.keys(j).map(function(_) { return j[_]; })
```

or simply:

```
Object.values(j)
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: Whoever reads this... Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead!

Comment: Just remember that Object.values() isn't [supported on any version of IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=Object.values)

Comment: IE doesn't support _anything_. Does it really matter what is and isn't compatible with it?

Comment: @Someone if MS doesn't support IE, why should any of the rest of us? Just pretend it was all a bad dream...

Answer (score 29):

```
function json2array(json){
    var result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(json);
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        result.push(json[key]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

See this complete explanation: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch5.html

Comment: This doesn't preserve keys.

Answer (score 26):

This will solve the problem:

```
const json_data = {"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7};

const arr = Object.keys(json_data).map((key) => [key, json_data[key]]);

console.log(arr);
```

Or using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method:

```
console.log(Object.entries(json_data));
```

In both the cases, output will be:

```
/* output: 
[['2013-01-21', 1], ['2013-01-22', 7]]
*/
```

The above solutions do not work for nested objects. For nested objects, we can do something like this:

```
const isObject = (obj) => {
  return typeof obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj) && obj !== null;
}

const objToArray = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    return [
      key, isObject(obj[key]) ? 
        objToArray(obj[key]) :
        obj[key]
    ];
  });    
}

const json_data = {
  "2013-01-21":1, 
  "2013-01-22":7,
  "ab":{"x":{"xa": 3, "xb": 4}, "y": 2},
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(objToArray(json_data)));
```

The output in this case will be:

```
/* output: 
[["2013-01-21",1],["2013-01-22",7],["ab",[["x",[["xa",3],["xb",4]]],["y",2]]]]
*/
```

Comment: Great. but doesn't work for nested objects.
var data = {"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7, "ab":{"x":1}}; 
returns
[["2013-01-21",1],["2013-01-22",7],["ab",{"x":1}]]

Comment: Edited the solution for nested objects with DFS approach.

Answer (score 8):

You can insert object items to an array as this

```js
 
 let obj2 = {"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7}
 
 console.log(Object.keys(obj2).map(key => [key, obj2[key]]))

let obj = {
  '1st': {
    name: 'stackoverflow'
  },
  '2nd': {
    name: 'stackexchange'
  }
};

// you can use Object.values(obj)
console.log(Object.values(obj))
 
// or you can use this instead. 
 let wholeArray = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

 
 console.log(wholeArray);
 console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: This is not the same json structure as the question. This will not work correctly with key/value pairs. It will only return an array of values.

Comment: @DylanPrem Thankyou for pointing out. Maybe the author edited the question. But anyway, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider having a json object we want to convert

```
const my_object = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

There is several solution you can use :

**1. [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)**

Theses functions convert any object to an array. One returns an array with all the keys, and the other all the values :

```
console.log(Object.keys(my_object))
// Output : ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

console.log(Object.values(my_object))
// Output : ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

I'm not sure to understand the initial question, but the solution would probably be

```
data.addRows(Object.values(my_object));
```

**2. [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)**

This function is a mix of the two above:

```
console.log(Object.entries(my_object))
// Output : [["key1", "value1"],  ["key2", "value2"],  ["key3", "value3"]]
```

It no use for the initial question, but this function is so usefull I had to mention it. Especially, when the *value_* are nested object.
Let say our values are objects like this :

```
const my_object = {
    "key1": {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    "key2": {"y": 25, "z": 26},
    "key3": {"much": "stuff"}
}
```

and we want to end up with an array like this

```
my_array = [
    {"key": "key1", "a": 1, "b": 2},
    {"key": "key2", "y": 25, "z": 26},
    {"key": "key3", "much": "stuff"}
]
```

We need to use `Object.entries()` to get all our key with their value. We will start with an overdetailed code :

```
my_array = Object.entries(my_object).map(function(entry){
   key = entry[0];
   value = entry[1];

   nested_object = value;
   nested_object.key = key;

   return nested_object;
});

console.log(my_array);
// Expected output : [
//    {"key": "key1", "a": 1, "b": 2},
//    {"key": "key2", "y": 25, "z": 26},
//    {"key": "key3", "much": "stuff"}
//]
```

We can make use of **[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** to simplify our code :

```
my_array = Object.entries(my_object).map(entry => {"key": entry[0], ...entry[1]});

console.log(my_array);
// Expected output : [
//    {"key": "key1", "a": 1, "b": 2},
//    {"key": "key2", "y": 25, "z": 26},
//    {"key": "key3", "much": "stuff"}
//]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a _"JSON object"_ or _"JSON array"_. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array but any data type can be encoded as JSON). Because JSON is text and nothing more, in order to process it, one has to decode it back into data structures equivalent to those used to create the JSON. In your example, `json_object` is a JavaScript object (and the quotes around the keys are not needed) and `json_array` is a JavaScript array. There is no trace of JSON in this response.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm thinking `json_object` as the object from my json. But i'll rename them 
 to avoid further confusions

Answer (score 3):

if the goal is to create an array of objects, here is a solution that will accomplish what you're trying to do using Object.keys():

```
const jsonResponse = '{"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7}'
// Only use json parse if the data is a JSON string.
const obj = typeof jsonResponse === 'string' ? JSON.parse(jsonResponse) : jsonResponse;
const data = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => data.push({[key]: obj[key]}))
// Example 2 - storing it directly in a variable using map
const arrayOfObjs = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({[key]: obj[key]}))
```

Or using Object.entries()

```
// Example 1
Object.entries(obj).forEach((array) => data.push({[array[0]]: array[1]}))
// Example 2
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => data.push({[key]: value}))
// Example 3 - Store it directly in a new variable using map
const arrayOfObjs = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Some correction to @Mister Aqua's
**SOLUTION**

```
const my_array = [];
    Object.entries(set_of_objects).map(function (entry) {
      const key = entry[0];
      const value = entry[1];

      const nested_object = {};

      nested_object[key] = value;
      my_array.push(nested_object);
    });
```

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score 1):

i got this error when i put my long JSON string in a hidden div and then
tried to convert it to JSON by this code-

```
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

spotted error yet?
yes, i forgot to add `.innerHTML` in first line.
so data is already an object. not a string. how can a object be parsed by JSON.parse?

JSON.parse is made for parsing strings. not objects.

Answer (score -10):

As simple as this !

```
var json_data = {"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7};
var result = [json_data];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That makes an array with one object inside it (the json data object).

Comment: @ Shivam, found it helpful ?