# Converting an object into json in specific format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My required json format is

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "1": {
      "attriba": "a1",
      "attribb": "b1",
      "label": "1",
      "attribc": false
    },
    "2": {
      "attriba": "a2",
      "label": "2",
      "attribc": false
    },
    "3": {
      "attriba": "a3",
      "label": "3",
      "attribc": false
    },
    "4": {
      "attriba": "none",
      "label": "4",
      "attribc": false
    },
    "5": {
      "attriba": "none",
      "label": "5",
      "attribc": false
    }
  }
}
```

Now normally I would create classes and fill them with data and call  "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject" to get the desired json string.

But in this case the format is such that I'm unable to figure out the class structure..

The top class I think would be like the following..

```
public class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty("nodes")]
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

     }
```

The bottom class ..

```
public class Nodedata
    {

        [JsonProperty("attriba")]
        public string Attriba { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attribb")]
        public string Attribb { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attribc")]
        public bool Attribc { get; set; }
    }
```

But, how do i manage the node class( values "1" to "5") which has no key value..

Any help will be sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: It could be a `Dictionary<int, NodeData>` where `nodes` is the reference to it?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel :Tx.., I just found something similar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581820/how-to-convert-json-array-to-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp?rq=1,

Comment: Here's a little example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zOLLXl

Comment: @JeroenVannevel would appreciate if you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183061/converting-an-object-to-json-in-specified-format-contd - Tx..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Node> nodes {get;set;}
}

public class Node
{
    public string attriba { get; set; }
    public string attribb { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public bool attribc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not know who gave you a minus point but this is exactly what Jeroen also said..