# Converting an object to json in specified format-contd

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

This question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180511/converting-an-object-into-json-in-specific-format).., rather than changing it, I'm asking a new one here..
My required json format is

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "1": {
            "2": {
                "attriba": "a2",
                "label": "2",
                "attribc": false
            },
            "3": {
                "attriba": "a3",
                "label": "3",
                "attribc": false
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "4": {
                "attriba": "none",
                "label": "4",
                "attribc": false
            },
            "5": {
                "attriba": "none",
                "label": "5",
                "attribc": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now normally I would create classes and fill them with data and call "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject" to get the desired json string.

But in this case the format is such that I'm unable to figure out the class structure..

The top class as per my last question would be like the following..

```
public class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty("nodes")]
        public Dictionary<string, Node> Nodes { get; set; }

     }
```

The bottom class ..

```
public class Nodedata
    {

        [JsonProperty("attriba")]
        public string Attriba { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attribb")]
        public string Attribb { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attribc")]
        public bool Attribc { get; set; }
    }
```

But, how do i manage the node class( values "1" & "6") which has again no key value and has a list of Nodedata objects..

Any help will be sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: It's a dictionary in a dictionary.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel So, should the Node class be ..
public class Node
   {
       public Dictionary<string, List<Nodedata>> data { get; set; }
   }
 ---and no JsonProperty?

Comment: No, that's a list in a dictionary. Try `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, NodeData>>` instead

Comment: There is no list in this example, in a list objects would be between []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class for nodes, 1 and 6 will be of type `Dictionary<string, Object>`

and your class for 2,3,4 and 5 will be as you designed it.

You shoudl get something like

```
BottomNode node1 = new BottomNode("a2", 2, false);
BottomNode node2 = new BottomNode("a3", 3, false);
BottomNode node3 = new BottomNode("none", 4, false);
BottomNode node4 = new BottomNode("none", 5, false);

Dictionary<string, Object> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
Dictionary<string, Object> dic6 = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

dic1.Add("2", node1);
dic1.Add("3", node2);
dic6.Add("4", node3);
dic6.Add("5", node4);

Dictionary<string, Object> nodes = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

nodes.Add("1", dic1);
nodes.Add("6", dic6);
```