# Convert JSON tree structure to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am new to JSON.  I have a JSON list in a tree structure like below:

```
{
  "complaint@simulator.amazonses.com": {
    "time": "2018-01-02T20:45:46.65Z",
    "type": "Complaint",
    "bounceType": "null",
    "bounceSubType": "null"
  },
  "struax@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-02T20:53:03Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "Suppressed"
  },
  "bounce-test@service.socketlabs.com": {
    "time": "2018-01-02T21:06:40.097Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "Suppressed"
  },
  "bounce@simulator.amazonses.com": {
    "time": "2018-01-02T21:08:02Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "General"
  },
  "jstrechay@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-05T06:31:39Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "General"
  },
  "leematt45@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-05T06:49:13Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "Suppressed"
  },
  "afbweb@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-07T12:50:38Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Transient",
    "bounceSubType": "General"
  },
  "bajanina2013@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-02T08:12:19Z",
    "type": "Bounce",
    "bounceType": "Transient",
    "bounceSubType": "MailboxFull"
  },
  "martin.bunt@example.org": {
    "time": "2018-01-05T07:00:24Z",
    "type": "Complaint",
    "bounceType": "null",
    "bounceSubType": "null"
  }
}
```

My SQL table columns are `Email`, `time`, `type`, `bounceType`, and `bounceSubType`.
How can I extract data from the JSON list and save it in the DB?

I am using this code:

```
string JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);
```

The JSON is in a tree structure and I am not able to fetch the parent node and the respective child in a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Json array to list of objects in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581820/how-to-convert-json-array-to-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also your sample isn't even valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do.  First, define a model class to hold the item data (you might already have such a class):

```
class BounceItem
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string BounceType { get; set; }
    public string BounceSubType { get; set; }
}
```

Next, deserialize the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, BounceItem>`:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, BounceItem>>(json);
```

The email addresses will become the keys in the dictionary, and values will be `BounceItem` objects containing the nested properties.  However, notice that the `Email` property in each `BounceItem` will not be populated at this point.

To fix that, post-process the dictionary to copy each key into the `Email` property on the corresponding item, storing results into a `List<BounceItem>`:

```
var list = dict.Select(kvp => { kvp.Value.Email = kvp.Key; return kvp.Value; }).ToList();
```

Now you have a list of model objects which should match up to your SQL table, and you can insert them using whatever method is appropriate for your database of choice.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5rzyCs

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple using **Json.NET** or using **Newtonsoft.Json.Linq**, if you are using **c#.NET**.

First Method:

```
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("your json string");
```

Second Method:

```
dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse("your json string");
```

After parsing you can pass the *jsonObject* to the DB.

Comment: thank for reply @Arun
  i am using this code
string JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);
the json is in tree  structure and i not able to fetch the parent node and the respected child in a list

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class based on your `Json` Responce. Than from that class deserialize your object like this

```
Class1 class1Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(str)
```

Comment: thank for reply @shyam
  i am using this code
string JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);
the json is in tree  structure and i not able to fetch the parent node and the respected child in a list

Comment: If you are not passing any class it will take dynamic. jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON); is actually jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSON); so you need to create a class that has same pattern as your json object and pass that class instead of dynamic