# Convert JS array string to C# List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a js stringify array `"["yellow", "black"]"` and I'm trying to convert it to C# list

Iv' tried to do the following code

```
stringList.Trim('[',']').ToList();
```

But the result is a list if every char

```
[ "y","e","l","l","o","w"...]
```

Any ideas of how can I do that?

THX

Comment: It would  be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Does https://app.quicktype.io?share=lbue2h2QQCHi2C3TTMS8 help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Json array to list of objects in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581820/how-to-convert-json-array-to-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You'll need to parse the JSON being sent to the server. ASP.Net will do this automatically if you specify the right model in the arguments to the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) APIs

```cs
JsonSerializer.Parse<List<string>>("[\"yellow\", \"black\"]");
```

For further information you can read [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).

Answer (score 1):

We use Newtonsoft for all JSON parsing:

```
string[] arr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>("[\"yellow\", \"black\"]");
```