# How can I customize the deserialization of a nested property in Json.net without adding attributes

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Suppose I have these classes:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string[] Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this JSON structure:

```
{
  "MyFoo":
  {
    "Stuff":"those,are,my,stuff"
  }
}
```

And I have a code path where a `JObject` is being converted to `Bar` using code like below:

```
myJObject.ToObject(typeof(Bar))
```

Now what I need to do is to supply the `ToObject` with a custom serializer to convert the string property `Stuff` into an array of string (using `string.Split(...).ToArray()`)

I was asked not to add attributes on the client class 'Bar' so after looking around it seemed like a `ContractResolver` is in order but the issue is that the resolver only lets me handle direct properties of the root Type, that is `Bar` in my example, and I can't register a `JsonConverter` on a nested property.

So my question to you guys is, is this even achievable using Json.net?

- Note that I need to do this not only for the `Bar` class but to an unlimited amount of classes with unknown structure so I can't hard-code a solution that will work for one type of class.

Comment: Check the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581820/how-to-convert-json-array-to-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: Is updating the JSON source to contain an actual JSON array instead of a comma separated string  out of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I don't see why you would need a `ContractResolver`.  You know that the properties you want to deserialize specially will always be of type `string[]`, so just make a converter that handles that type.  Maybe something like this:

```
public class CsvStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null) 
            return null;

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
            return ((string)token).Split(',');

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array) 
            return token.ToObject<string[]>(serializer);

        throw new JsonException("Unexpected token type: " + token.Type);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, to use it with your `JObject`, create a new `JsonSerializer` instance, add the converter to it, and pass the serializer to the `ToObject()` method like this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new CsvStringConverter());

var bar = myJObject.ToObject<Bar>(serializer);
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qmeBoh