# Parsing Json and put in single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I tried to parse my json data and put it in single array but got no luck. I tried the answers in this link [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array) but still not the exact result that i wanted.

here's my json

```
{
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "code": "00011",
      "name": "Test 1"
    },
    {
      "code": "00082",
      "name": "Test 2"
    },
    {
      "code": "00083",
      "name": "Test 3"
    }
   ]
}
```

and i want to put it in one array. The result should be like the code below.

```
var myarray = [{"code": "00011", "name": "test 1"},{"code": "00082", "name": "test 2"},{"code": "00083", "name": "test 3"}];
```

Comment: `var myarray = myParsedJson.Sheet1;`…?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've got the json as a string within your javascript? Something like:

```
var json = '{"Sheet1": [{"code": "00011","name": "Test 1"},{"code": "00082","name": "Test 2"},{"code": "00083","name": "Test 3"}]}';
```

If that's the case first parse the json, which will turn it into an object literal:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
```

You can then access the array you want, as shown below:

```
var myarray = parsed.Sheet1;
```