# Typescript: Cannot access property from inside a function

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

```
export class DuyurularPage {
    duyurular: any;
    loading: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loadingPage: LoadingController,
        platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

        this.loading = this.loadingPage.create({
            content: `
            <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>`
        });

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();

            var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
                this.duyurular = jsonData.notification.payload;
            };

            alert
            window["plugins"].OneSignal
            .startInit("12312412412412", "1231241212")
            .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
            .endInit();
        });
    }
}
```

`var notificationOpenedCallback = function...` ← Inside this function, I cannot access `this.duyurular`.

I have to write this array (`duyurular`) up from json. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because this function below has the wrong scope.

```
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      this.duyurular = jsonData.notification.payload;
    };
```

Change it to a fat arrow function or define the scope outside of this block:

Preferred option:

```
    var notificationOpenedCallback = (jsonData) =>  {
      this.duyurular = jsonData.notification.payload;
    };
```

Outside the function option:

```
    const self = this;

    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      self.duyurular = jsonData.notification.payload;
    };
```

---

As for building the array, the data will come in as a JSON object. You need to get the data you want for your component out of the JSON and use it to build the array. See this question for more advice on how to do that: [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

Comment: Very, very much thanks :) But ı have one more question.

Comment: I did as you said, I can alert () the incoming data, but do not get in the html page.

      <ion-card class="card-background-page" *ngFor="let item of duyurular">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="./assets/img/avatar.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-card-content>{{item.body}}</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

Comment: The data will come in as a JSON object. You need to get the data you want for your component out of the JSON and use it to build the array. See this question for more advice on how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array

Comment: Thank u very much