# How do I get an array of countries from this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
[
 {
   "ISO 3166 Country Code": "AD",
   "Country": "Andorra",
   "Latitude": 42.5,
   "Longitude": 1.5
 },
 {
   "ISO 3166 Country Code": "AE",
   "Country": "United Arab Emirates",
   "Latitude": 24,
   "Longitude": 54
 },
 {
   "ISO 3166 Country Code": "AF",
   "Country": "Afghanistan",
   "Latitude": 33,
   "Longitude": 65
 },
 {
   "ISO 3166 Country Code": "AG",
   "Country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
   "Latitude": 17.05,
   "Longitude": -61.8
 }
]
```

Comment: There is only one JSON object. What you have is an object literal. What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? What output do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
var countries = [];

fetch("url.json").then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        countries.push(data[i].Country);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [{"ISO 3166 Country Code":"AD","Country":"Andorra","Latitude":42.5,"Longitude":1.5},{"ISO 3166 Country Code":"AE","Country":"United Arab Emirates","Latitude":24,"Longitude":54},{"ISO 3166 Country Code":"AF","Country":"Afghanistan","Latitude":33,"Longitude":65},{"ISO 3166 Country Code":"AG","Country":"Antigua and Barbuda","Latitude":17.05,"Longitude":-61.8}];

let countries = arr.map(v => v.Country);
console.log(countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [...]// posted in question
var countries = arr.map(function(element) { return element['Country'] })
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most concise way to do it would be with `array.map`. However, if you consider performance to be an issue, using a for loop could be a magnitude of ten faster.
See the following link for more information about performance 
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7