# Check a key on a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

We are getting JSON string two ways:

```
"{"phoneNumber":[{"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}"
```

Or

```
"{"phoneNumber":["0099887765"]}"
```

We have to convert `"{"phoneNumber":[{"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}"` in `"{"phoneNumber":["0099887765"]}"` way

Is there any way to write a JavaScript to determine which JSON has "add" key and which one don't have.

Comment: You can use `Object.hasOwnProperty(key)` method or simply `if(object.key){}`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. So by the time you're doing this check, you're not dealing with JSON anymore, you'll have parsed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse the JSON, you'll have an array with two entries (each objects) if it's the first style, or an array with one entry that's a string. So:

```
function handle(theJSON) {
    let parsed = JSON.parse(theJSON);
    if (typeof parsed.phoneNumber[0] === "object") {
        parsed.phoneNumber = [parsed.phoneNumber.find(o => o.add).add[0]];
    }
    console.log(parsed);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function handle(theJSON) {
    let parsed = JSON.parse(theJSON);
    if (typeof parsed.phoneNumber[0] === "object") {
        parsed.phoneNumber = [parsed.phoneNumber.find(o => o.add).add[0]];
    }
    console.log(parsed);
}
    
handle('{"phoneNumber":[{"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}');

handle('{"phoneNumber":["0099887765"]}');
```

Or if you need an ES5 version:

```
function handle(theJSON) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(theJSON);
    if (typeof parsed.phoneNumber[0] === "object") {
        parsed.phoneNumber = [parsed.phoneNumber.find(function(o) { return o.add; }).add[0]];
    }
    console.log(parsed);
}
```

Comment: We might get the json : "{"email":[{"remove":["ind@gmail.com"]},{"add":["indra2121@gmail.com"]}]}"

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee - Just generalize the above. If you need to discover the name of the one property in the wrapper (which suggests a design issues somewhere), you can get it from `Object.keys(parsed)[0]`.

Comment: Actually from a third party application, I am getting different types of json.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee - If your code doesn't know, by the nature of the API it's calling, what the shape of the result is, that's a design error -- in the API you're calling.

Comment: Actually from a third party application, I am getting different types of json. 
Example : To modify phone number I am getting json: 
'{"phoneNumber":[{"add":["0099844465"],"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}'
for update email :
{"email":[{"remove":["ind@gmail.com"]},{"add":["indra2121@gmail.com"]}]}" 
For add user:
{"username":["user1"],"password":["pass@123"],"email":["ind2121@gmail.com"]}
I need determine the operation and make a common json like:
{"attribute":"value"} 
I have no control on third party API/application.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee - Right, so again, you'd do it as in the comment above. It's unfortunate you have to deal with an API that makes you do that.

Comment: Is there any way to find "add" is there or not in a json keys. 
for two types of JSON: 
{"username":["user1"],"password":["pass@123"],"email":["ind2121@gmail.com"]}
or
{"phoneNumber":[{"add":["0099844465"],"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}
so I can do it. 
Thank you for your support.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee - I told you how to do it [several comments ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249069/check-a-key-on-a-json-object/53249166?noredirect=1#comment93386462_53249166).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` to return true/false if "add" is a property on any object in the array. Here's a general solution:

```js
const json = '{"phoneNumber":[{"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}';
const data = JSON.parse(json);

function checkForKey(data, { arrayKey, searchKey }) {
  return data[arrayKey].some(obj => obj[searchKey]);
}

const hasAdd = checkForKey(data, {arrayKey: 'phoneNumber', searchKey: 'add' });
console.log(hasAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check, finally push only the phoneNumbers with `add` index. Hope this helps :)

```js
const expected = {'phoneNumber':[]};
let str = '{"phoneNumber":[{"add":["0099844465"],"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}';

const st_obj = JSON.parse(str);
for (var k in st_obj['phoneNumber']) {
        if (st_obj['phoneNumber'][k].hasOwnProperty('add'))           {
           expected['phoneNumber'].push(st_obj['phoneNumber'][k]['add']);
        }
}

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score -1):

just check if add is top level propery

```
if(obj['add']) {....}
```

if it is exists then `if` will be true, if not it will return `undefined` and `if` will be false,

if you should check it in array of objects, you can use the same logic with `find` method from array prototype

```
phoneNumber.find(obj => obj['add']);
```

Comment: `add` isn't a property of the top-level object of the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether the `add` key exists by converting the JSON into array:

[How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

With that you are able to check if the key exists by checking whether the key is undefined:

```
obj["phonenumber"]["add"] != undefined
```

Comment: `add` isn't a property of the top-level object of the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

use `let obj = JSON.parse('{"phoneNumber":[{"remove":["0099887769"]},{"add":["0099887765"]}]}')` to convert it to object.
then iterate it and fetch value and push it into new object