# How do I convert this javascript object into an array using javascript without arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

This comes through GTM as an `object` that I have to convert to an `array`, so that I can loop through it.

I've written a `forEach` statement for it, but I can't seem to format this properly to work.

(full disclosure, I'm not a developer, I'm just trying to muddle my way through GTM)

I've tried using `Object.entries(obj)`, but the result was multiple `arrays`.

```
{
  0: {
    category_id: '',
    cart_entry_id: 0,
    quantity: 3,
    product_id: '678294',
    unit_price: 5.29,
    product_name: 'Office Depot® Brand 8-Pocket Poly Organizer, Assorted Colors (No Color Choice)',
  },
  2: {
    category_id: '543867',
    cart_entry_id: 2,
    quantity: 1,
    product_id: '448906',
    unit_price: 34.99,
    product_name: 'Realspace® All-Pile Studded Chair Mat, 36" x 48";, Clear',
  },
  3: {
    category_id: '543867',
    cart_entry_id: 3,
    quantity: 1,
    product_id: '493876',
    unit_price: 179.99,
    product_name: 'Realspace® MFTC 200 Mesh Multifunction Ergonomic Mid-Back Task Chair, Black',
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a sample of what you expect in the array?

Comment: Welcome J.R. Dunn. Always be sure to give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case you just have arbitrary objects that need to turn into an array. What is in those doesn't matter, so trimming it down to a smaller sample will make it easier to understand the question and make it more likely you'll get good responses.

Comment: Just apply `Object.values(input)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll try to minimize it.

Comment: What do you mean by "without arrow functions"? Those are a standard feature in ES6, but you can always use the old `function() { ... }` form.

Comment: Google Tag Manager doesn't support ES6, so I can't use them. That's why I had to post the question. All answers I found included those.

Comment: Could you please when you edit your message keep the formating I have done like 3 times instead of redoing the same mistakes? I did vote up your question but now I believe you don't deserve it.

Comment: I'm really sorry Dimitri, this is my first time posting here. I'm just trying to figure this stuff out. I'll delete the question. This was a mistake.

Comment: Never mind. I can't delete. I'll keep looking for answers elsewhere. Thank you all for your time, and I'm sorry I couldn't explain my problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have any object like this:

```
{
  0: 'some data',
  1: 'some data',
  2: 'some data'
}
```

You can easily turn it into an array with this:

```js
const input = {
  0: 'some data',
  1: 'some data',
  2: 'some data'
};

const output = Object.values(input);

console.log(output);
```

If you need to ensure the keys are always in the same order (which you probably should) you can add a sort on it first.

```js
const input = {
  0: 'some data',
  1: 'some data',
  2: 'some data'
};

// entries turns the object into an array of arrays with each
// entry being [key, value].
const output = Object.entries(input)
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  .map(i => i[1]);

console.log(output);
```

Since you asked without array functions, just change the arrow functions to not arrow functions (though not sure why you'd want to):

```js
const input = {
  0: 'some data',
  1: 'some data',
  2: 'some data'
};

// entries turns the object into an array of arrays with each
// entry being [key, value].
const output = Object.entries(input)
  .sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0] })
  .map(function (i) { return i[1] });

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This last snippet fixed everything. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this object is something you have already and your question is containing a printout of that object.

```
for(var i in json_data)
   result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
```

[check out this question for a more through answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you object is an ecommerce transaction (but could be cart, or any other) object from dataLayer, and that you'd like to convert it to an array.

1. set ecommerce object as DL variable

[DL variable: ecommerce.purchase object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO31F.png)

so it would look like this:
[GTM debugger: ecommerce object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRps2.png)

2] convert it to an array using Custom JS variable:

```html
function(){
  var a = JSON.stringify({{DL EE purchase array}});
  return a;
}
```

That would convert ecommerce.purchase from object into an array [string data type].