# JSON object to Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im seeing a lot of answers to this in simple arrays but I need the keys and value. I have a json object but need an array. The object looks like this:

```
{"Food":"Starbucks", "Job":"Electrician"}
```

I just need a simple array like this:

```
["Food" => "Starbucks", "Job" => "Electrician"]
```

Edit: Im not sure how to type it out. Just need to be able to do an array.map and get the keys and values in javascript.

Here is the final code that I am trying:

```
const details = jsonObject;

{details.map(function(item,idx){
                return<DetailCell>
                    <Label>{idx}</Label>
                    <Text style={TextStyle}>{item}</Text>
                </DetailCell>
             })}
```

Label should be the key and the Text should be the value.

Comment: What does the `=>` represent in your example?

Comment: JavaScript does not have a syntax like `=>` in arrays. Also, you have an object, no need for JSON prefix.

Comment: Yea this `=>` used in php ..

Comment: What is the functionality of => symbol in this case ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use this array?  Assume there is a function which returns the array you want.  What code would you write using the return value?

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989167/2100126 and slightly modify it if you like to preserve keys. (`result[key] = json[key];`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
[{"Food" : "Starbucks"}, {"Job" : "Electrician"}]
```

Comment: This can't be really, then you need to `arr[0].Food` to get `Starbucks` out which is way more harder then `obj.Food`

Answer (score -1):

To declare a literal array value is something like this in JSON in node.

{JSONVarWithArrayValue : [0,0,0,0]}