# How to convert a js object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

My data:

`{product_quantity: {quantity: 13, code: "AAA", warehouse: "1000",}}`

product_quantity is an field from a mongodb json data.

I need to convert it into this:

`{"product_quantity": [{"quantity": 13, "code": "AAA", "warehouse": "1000"}]`

How can I transform an object into array with its keys and values?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)

Comment: `[quantity]`? Hard to tell where the difficulty is...

Comment: No, I need the same variable to be converted. Not creating an array and inserting data into it

Comment: `quantity = [quantity];` It's till hard to tell what you are trying to do and what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: So my data comes from a mongodb. I put it as const to exemplify, to simplify the question. I need to convert the data using some method. Because I will need to continue my code using the data transformed into an array

Comment: Read [ask] and create a proper [mcve] of the problem

Comment: `const` means you can't change what it references... I don't see how your requirement is  real. Assign it to something else and pass your new reference back where you need it.

Comment: @ALBINO33 json you  want is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json you want is not valid , you can use this

```
let productQuantity={product_quantity:{quantity:13, code:"AAA", warehouse:"1000"}};

productQuantity.product_quantity=[productQuantity.product_quantity];

console.log(JSON.stringify(productQuantity));
```

result

```
{"product_quantity":[{"quantity":13,"code":"AAA","warehouse":"1000"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

const data = [quantity];

output;
[{quantity: 13, code: "AAA", warehouse: "1000",}];

Comment: I've edited the question, I think it is now clearer to understand. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).